# How can I use a ui slider to change a audio mixer volume?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Since in the latest unity editor version there is no anymore the Dynamic option I need to call the function from the script with the parameter but not sure what to do with it.

On a Canvas I have attached the SettnigsMenu script :

[image: Canvas SettingsMenu]

The script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class SettingsMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;

    public void SetVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("Volume", volume);
    }

    public void SetQuality(int qualityIndex)
    {
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }
}
```

Then on the Hierarchy again I have a Volume Slider (UI Slider)
I clicked the plus to add an event then dragged down the Canvas and then selecting the SetVolume (float)

[image: SetVolume with parameter]

Now I have in the On Value Changed also a field parameter with the value 0 in.

[image: Parameter 0 value in the on value changed]

But now how do I make that when changing the volume in my game it will change the volume in the audio mixer ? In older unity editor version I could selected Dynamic float for the SetVolume but it's not exist anymore in the latest unity version.

Same problem with the SetQuality function.

Since the Dynamic option is not exist I'm not sure how to make that the finctions in the script will effect and change the ui values in the editor like the volume audio mixer or the dropdown quality that should change the quality level in the Edit > Project Settings... > Quality

[image: Quality settings in editor]

Comment: Take a look at this post https://johnleonardfrench.com/articles/the-right-way-to-make-a-volume-slider-in-unity-using-logarithmic-conversion/

Comment: @SagiZiv  The problem is that in unity3d version 2019.2.5f1 the dynamic functions not exist. It was in version 2018 but not in the latest one. I installed both versions and checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `SettingsMenu.cs` you need to add a reference to the slider and assign it in the inspector.

Then in your SetVolume method, you need to read the value from the slider.
You can then do whatever you like with the volume.

Same goes for the dropdown. Add a reference to it and extract the selected index from the control.

EDIT: dont forget to add the correct `using` for the Slider.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SettingsMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Slider _volumeSlider;

    public void SetVolume()
    {
        float volume = _volumeSlider.value;
        audioMixer.SetFloat("Volume", volume);
    }
}
```

Comment: He doesn't need reference to the slider, in the unityevent he can use the dynamic functions

Comment: @SagiZiv The problem is that in unity3d version 2019.2.5f1 the dynamic functions not exist. It was in version 2018 but not in the latest one. I installed both versions and checked.

Comment: @DanielLip Oh, my bad…
Sorry about that